# Lucene Chinese Analyzer .NET

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

There are a couple of Chinese Analyzers for Java, one being SEN, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a Chinese Analyzer for .NET?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the contrib project https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/src/contrib/Analyzers/Cn/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't know that existed. I am implementing this with Sitecore's Lucene indexer, however it seems to get caught in a loop and will not finish. I'm assuming that code has been tested. I noticed a few TODO comments.

Comment: I'm unsure unfortunately - have you had any luck with it?

Answer (score 0):

Both [PanGuAnalyzer](http://pangusegment.codeplex.com) and [IKAnalyzer](https://github.com/stanzhai/IKAnalyzer.NET) have .NET version for [lucene.net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/).